# How to compose Future of Either/Disjunction in Scala

Tags: scala, future, scalaz, monad-transformers, either

Suppose I have the following functions to compose:

```
 val mayFail1: Int => Error \/ Int          = ???
 val slowAndMayFail: Int => Error \/ String = ???
 val mayFail2: String => Error \/ Int       = ???
 val mayFail3: String => Error \/ Int       = ???

 val mayFail: Int => Error \/ Int = {x =>
   for {
     x1 <- mayFail1(x)
     s  <- slowAndMayFail(x1)
     x2 <- mayFail2(s)
     x3 <- mayFail3(x2)         
   } yield x3
 }
```

The function `mayFail` is slow because of `slowAndMayFail`, so I would like it to return a *future* of `Error \/ Int`.

The straightforward approach is probably to make `slowAndMayFail` return `scalaz.Future[Error\/Int]]`, make all other functions (`mayFail1`, `mayFail2`, etc.) return `Future[Error\/Int]]` as well and then add `EitherT` to compose them together.

Does it make sense ? Are there easier/simpler solutions ?

I know that `scalaz` provides [Task](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.concurrent.Task) but I am sticking with `Future` for now.

Comment: Well, you could just wrap the whole `for` in `Future { }`

Comment: @Kolmar You are probably right. Thank you. It was a silly question. What if `slowAndMayFail` already returns `Future[Error\/Int]]` ?

Comment: You could also just fail in the future, which is essentially just a disjunction with a throwable left side and an extra unsatisfied state.

Comment: I think you're got the correct approach. However just a minor clarification: you would be returning an EitherT[Future,Error,Int], not just using EitherT to compose them together. You might also want to look at Kleisli composition which could achieve the same kind of thing

Comment: @TravisBrown Yes, it looks simpler. What if `slowAndMayFail` returns `Future[Error\/Int]` or `Future[Try[Int]]` and I cannot change it ?

Comment: @Michael You can still `flatMap` the future on the spot to collapse the two levels.