# Composing Future and Try

Tags: scala, exception, future

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140753/how-to-compose-future-of-either-disjunction-in-scala)

Suppose I have a function, which returns a `Future[String]`, and a function `String => Try[Int]`:

```
val slowAsync : Int => Future[String] = ...
val mayFail   : String => Try[Int] = ...
```

Suppose I am composing them to make a new function `Int => Future[Int]`:

```
val composed : Int => Future[Int] = {x => 
  for (str <- slowAsync(x); y <- Future(mayFail(s).get)) yield y
}
```

The `composed` is probably working but I don't like this `Future(mayFail(s).get)`. How would you fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use fromTry:

```
val x = slowAsync(1) flatMap (s => Future.fromTry(mayFail(s)))
```

Comment: Nice, I completely forgot about that method. Also if `mayFail` is a function, you can further simplify the `flatMap` body via point-free style to `flatMap(mayFail andThen Future.fromTry)`, although it's just a matter of personal preference.